# Exclusive-Or probability for multiple events

Tags: probability, elementary-set-theory

For independent, non-mutually exclusive events, the probability that A or B will be true, but not both is,

$P(A \oplus B) = P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A)P(B)$

Is there a similar formula for multiple events (A,B,C,D,E.....)?

For example, there a 365 events (A1,A2,A3....A365). Each equally likely with equal probability of 0.2. How would I do $P(A1 \oplus A2 \oplus A3 \oplus A4$.....?

Comment: What you mean under $A \oplus B$ ? symmetrical difference?

Comment: @zkutch Like $P(A \oplus B \oplus C \oplus D \oplus E) = ? $

Comment: I guess what you want, but asked about exact definition for $A \oplus B$.

Comment: @zkutch That is the definition: $P(A \oplus B) = P(A \cup B) - P(A \cap B) \\= P(A) + P(B) - 2P(A)P(B)$

Comment: You mean https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symmetric_difference - yes?

Comment: @zkutch I suspect that the $\oplus$ notation is used in the context of Boolean rings. Indeed the symmetric difference.

Comment: @drhab. Thanks. I think same - if you have time, please, take look at my answer.

Comment: Indeed, the symmetric difference makes the set algebra an abelian group with the empty set as neutral element, therefore it makes sense to use an addition symbol for it.

Answer (score 1):

We have something like [Inclusion–exclusion principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle).
$$P(A \oplus B \oplus C) =P(A) + P(B) +P(C) -2 P(A)P(B)-2 P(A)P(C)-2 P(C)P(B)+4P(A)P(B)P(C)$$
Generally:
$$P(A_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus A_n) = \sum_{i=1}^{n}P(A_i) - 2\sum_{1 \leqslant i < j \leqslant n}P(A_i)P(A_j) + \\ + 4\sum_{1 \leqslant i < j < k\leqslant n} P(A_i)P(A_j)P(A_k) +\cdots + (-1)^{n-1}2^{n-1}P(A_1) \cdot \cdots \cdot P(A_n)$$

Comment: Ok lets say there a 365 events (A1,A2,A3....A365). Each equally likely with equal probability of 0.2. How would I do $P(A1 \oplus A2 \oplus A3 \oplus A4$.....?

Comment: I wrote general formula, so you can write it for $n=365$. But if you share your task, may be there will be some consideration.

Comment: I don't know how to put the general formula in a calculator.

Comment: What you mean - in which calculator?

Answer (score 0):

Just consider:

$$\begin{align}\mathsf P(A{\oplus}B{\oplus}C)&=\mathsf P(A{\oplus}B)+\mathsf P(C)-2\mathsf P((A{\oplus}B){\cap}C)\\[1ex]&=\mathsf P(A{\oplus}B)+\mathsf P(C)-2\mathsf P((A{\cap}C){\oplus}(B{\cap}C))\\[1ex]&={\mathsf P(A)+\mathsf P(B)+\mathsf P(C)-{2({\mathsf P(A{\cap}B)+\mathsf P(A{\cap}C)+\mathsf P(B{\cap}C)})}+4\mathsf P(A{\cap}B{\cap}C)}\end{align}$$

So...

Comment: ok lets say there are 365 events (A1,A2,A3....A365). Each equally likely with equal probability of 0.2. How would I do $P(A1 \oplus A2 \oplus A3 \oplus A4$..... ) in a calculator?